# USGS Layers in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I'm just wondering what's the best source for USGS topo layers/tiles for Google Maps? I've got a kml file from ARCGIS that works fine in Google Earth but doesn't give me all the different zoom levels in Google Maps. I know terraserver was a good source but I've heard support is spotty at best with server downtime a problem. Obviously free would be best as we are a non-profit and are providing the maps free for planning purposes, but would be willing to pay if it were worth it. Thanks in advance